# How do i simplify the PRIMARY id in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

If you had 500,000 products in a table, would it be normal to let the PRIMARY id AUTO_INCREMENT to that amount?   id = 500000

Are there any standard models for dealing with large tables?

Maybe for example maybe using letters: AA100.

Im looking for a strategy that will work for any amount, thanks.

Comment: Why `AA100` format will work with large tables and a numeric value won't?

Comment: What's wrong with large numbers for IDs ?

Answer (score 0):

> If you had 500,000 products in a table, would it be normal to let the PRIMARY id AUTO_INCREMENT to that amount?

Yes, that's normal. (Or whatever other value the primary key ends up at. Some replication schemes may leave it at a multiple of the number of rows, in fact, and that's perfectly fine.)

Large numbers are not a problem. Computers are excellent at dealing with numbers!

Comment: Hi. I find it hard to believe that I have to manage my products based on some random number. I could have a bag of chips with an id of 300,000 and a LCD tv with an id of 300,001 . Its not organized. Obviously Im a noob and lacking some concept Can you fill me in on how things like products can be organized.

Comment: The primary key isn't supposed to keep things "organized", though! It's just a way of identifying rows.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with autoincrementing an id up to half a million values. In fact, that isn't even particularly large.

Having said that, id you're concerned about slanting your index, you could use [`uuid`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) instead.

Comment: Ooh… no, don't do that. UUIDs have *horrible* performance characteristics when used as a primary key: http://kccoder.com/mysql/uuid-vs-int-insert-performance/

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL PRIMARY id AUTO_INCREMENT as purely int is the ultimate thing to do. If you are afraid that 500,000  might too big for the column size capacity. I want to encourage you to read [MySQL Integer Type documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) int is of size 4 byte  thus it far bigger than your expected size and will be very appropriate for your case. NOTE:  using patterns like AA100 will involve some algorithm which will definitely come with some performance cost.